# Customizing an ActionBar using ActionbarSherlock and jeremyfeinstein slidingmenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an action sherlock bar and I need customize this control as the following picture. I need a pseudocode or similar simple example. I downloaded the library, examples, and I have been searching in this site and google, but I could not find something like this.
Sorry if the information is incomplete, in that case I'll edit the post with the information you need. Thanks.

Note:

1. I do not want to use **android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout**, **ActionBarDrawerToggle**. I need the sherlock slide effect.
2. I need a image and label above the list of menu options (LISTVIEW) (see the right image).

[image]

In the future I'm going to need a bar like below (the style must be similar to [see this link](http://static.knowyourmobile.com/sites/knowyourmobilecom/files/styles/insert_main_wide_image/public/3/97/wwdc2013vs2012.jpg?itok=rFcX4ShB))

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**SidingMenu layout:**

You should set a `ListView` as menu layout. Next, create `sliding_menu_header.xml` layout with `ImageView` and `TextView` inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/image_source"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you can inflate this layout and set it as `ListView`'s header view:

```
View menuHeader = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu_header, null);
mListView.addHeaderView(menuHeader);
mListView.setAdapter(mYourMenuAdapter);
```

**ActionBar layout:**

You can add a custom view to the `ActionBar`. In your case the layout can be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then add below lines to your `onCreate` method:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);

Button button1 = actionBar.getCustomView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = actionBar.getCustomView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Hope it will be helpful to you. If my answer is incomplete please comment and I'll update it.

Answer (score 4):

Implement "Sliding Menu" it's perfect with Sherlock ActionBar

**Link library**

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

**VideoTutorial for implement two libraries**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IW6idyV0CZQ

**EDIT**

```
//pre-ICS
if (actionBarSherlock instanceof ActionBarImpl) {
    enableEmbeddedTabs(actionBarSherlock);

//ICS and forward
} else if (actionBarSherlock instanceof ActionBarWrapper) {
    try {
        Field actionBarField = actionBarSherlock.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
        actionBarField.setAccessible(true);
        enableEmbeddedTabs(actionBarField.get(actionBarSherlock));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error enabling embedded tabs", e);
    }
}

//helper method
private void enableEmbeddedTabs(Object actionBar) {
    try {
        Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error marking actionbar embedded", e);
    }
}
```

look that link:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/hmmB1JqDeCk

When you had tabs on your action bar you can asing one style for your tabs, border, backgroundImage, gravity and you give button appearance.

Look:

> http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/05/13/themes-for-the-android-actionbar-tabs/

Try it and tell us.

Comment: @Gaston F. did it work? please accept my answer if i helped you

Comment: thanks for your links, I had seen that information, these libraries and examples I had already installed but I could not do the screen2 (with the imagecontrol over the links) and I could not add button1 and button2 on the topbar (see the last image). If you have a solution, please I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Do you want that buttons like "tabs" or only buttons with one icon?

Comment: if you refer to topbar, I need a button (please see this [link](http://static.knowyourmobile.com/sites/knowyourmobilecom/files/styles/insert_main_wide_image/public/3/97/wwdc2013vs2012.jpg?itok=rFcX4ShB))

Comment: +1 thanks for your time and the information posted, but i resolved the actionbar problem  adding two buttons using `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.MY_VIEW)`, This customview has a LinearLayout within a RelativeLayout, the LinearLayaout has a property android:layout_centerInParent="true". Anyway your links helped me looked for other alternatives. +1
Now I have to solve the problem of screen 2.

Comment: I'm glad for you so much, always it's a pleasure help.

Answer (score 1):

From your picture it seams you want to scroll the actionbar too. That's not possible (to my knowledge). For something like that to work you have to make your custom actionbar (as a ordinary layout) and handle the visibility change and scroll by yourself. You can also check actionbar_compat (appcompat_v7). if basically offers the same functionality as ActionbarSherlock and SlidingMenu combined. http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html. And the menu can contain heterogenous items, if that's your concern.